# Python findall(), нахождение строки между двумя точками

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строковая информация: **AA÷ns8EohXe¬AD** (это часть строки), мне нужено вытащить  **ns8EohXe**. Я заметил зависимость в том, что **нужная мне информация находиться между AA÷  и   ¬AD**.

Т. к. мне нужно получить array значений, использую findall().

**Вопрос заключается в том, как задать регулярное выражение, чтобы найти определенную информацию, зная соседние точки, между которыми она находится?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
import re
comp = re.compile(r'AA÷(\S*?)¬AD')
comp.findall('AA÷ns8EohXe¬ADAA÷ng53he¬AD')
Out[14]: ['ns8EohXe', 'ng53he']
```

Если это просто строка, иначе

```
comp = re.compile(r'AA÷(.*?)¬AD')
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
s = u'dsfdsfds34523453AA÷ns8EohXe¬ADdfasdfaa sdfa dfas df a453AA÷ns8EohXe¬ADdfsd2341234123412453AA÷ns8EohXe¬ADdf 34fsdf'
print re.findall(u'AA÷(.+?)¬AD', s)
```

Comment: Бывает, что пустая строка тоже имеет смысловую нагрузку, я бы не стал её отбрасывать и использовал * вместо +.

Comment: Согласен с вами. У видел ваш коммент и тоже об этом подумал. Автору должно быть виднее, но в общем случае 

    r'AA÷(.*?)¬AD'

более правильно

Comment: Да, автору, конечно, виднее, я поэтому и написал, чтобы у него был выбор)